# Java Regexp Groups

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I need a expression to extract some alternatives. The input is:

```
asd11sdf33sdf55sdfg77sdf
```

I need the 11 33 and 55 but not 77.

I tried first:

```
.*(((11)|(33)|(55)).*)+.*
```

So I got only 55. But with lazy (non greedy)

```
.*?(((11)|(33)|(55)).*)+.*
```

I got only 11. How to get all?

regards Thomas

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. Do you want to assert that 11, 33, and 55 are present in the string, but that 77 isn't? Is the order of numbers relevant? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want all 11 or 33 or 55. In aa33ss33dd33ee I need 3 times 33

Comment: I use:
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(11|33|55)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("asd11sdf33sdf55sdfg77sdf");
    int start = 0;
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        matches.add(m.group());
    }
    System.err.println("matches = " + matches);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `(?!77)(\d\d)` as a `Pattern` and `while (m.find()) { m.group(1) }` where `m` is a `Matcher`.

Comment: This finds any two-digit number, not just 11, 33 or 55 (although it's unclear to me what @tricpod would need a regex for this anyway).

Comment: Oh my question was not precise enough. 11 33 55 are only an example.

Comment: Then this is the correct solution. +1 for best use of crystal ball today.

Answer (score 1):

Groups are fixed, you cannot use "+" on a group to get a list of matches. You have to do this with a loop:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((11)|(33)|(55))");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("asd11sdf33sdf55sdfg77sdf");
    int start = 0;
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        matches.add(m.group());
    }
    System.err.println("matches = " + matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
.*?(11|33|55)
```

as your regexp to compile the pattern, and use the loop in fge's answer. (and I think his answer is more universal and meaningful...

This is because the .* or something after (11|33|55) in your regexp matches the whole string after 11. (and if you use greedy match the .* before (11|33|55) will match the whole string before 55... just because it is greedy)

This way you will get a match whose match(1) is 11, find() is the match of string after 11.

tested with http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html